# How can I proof that a complete binary tree has \lceil n/2 \rceil leaves?

Tags: binary-search-tree

Given a complete binary tree with n nodes. I'm trying to proof that a complete binary tree has exactly \lceil n/2 \rceil leaves.
I think I can do this by induction.

For h(t)=0, the tree is empty. So there are no leaves and the claim holds for an empty tree.

For h(t)=1, the tree has 1 node, that also is a leaf, so the claim holds.
Here I'm stuck, I don't know what to choose as induction hypothesis and how to do the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

If the root node is not a leaf, then it has two subtrees, which you solve for recursively. Each subtree has one more leaf than non-leaf nodes, so when you add the root (which has one more non-leaf than leaf nodes!) and both subtrees together, you get back to one more leaf than non-leaf nodes, or to put it another way, leaf nodes make up half of the number of nodes, rounded up.